# Select list propagated from php incrementing time not starting from the first entry

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for the title I had a hard time trying to explain my issue.

I have a select list propagated from php with a list of times that are incrementing every 15 minutes. Here is my code

```
<select class="form-control" id="starttime">
<?php
$increment = 900;
$day_in_increments = range( 0, (86400 - $increment), $increment );
array_walk( $day_in_increments, function( $time ) {
    printf( '<option>%s</option>', date( 'g:i A', $time ) );
} );
?>
</select>
```

For some reason when I run this code in the file all in its own with ONLY the code you see it starts from 12:00 AM as it should. And looks like this.

[image: time starting from 12:00 am]

But for some reason when I plug it into my page that I am going to use it on the time starts at 4:00 PM.[image]

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this is happening or even what could be causing it. For security reasons, I cannot show all the HTML on my page but I can tell you that I am using bootstrap v3 and this `select` is part of a [modal](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/)

I am also using the following scripts on my page as well as the corresponding `.js` files.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sweet-alert.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/select2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lightbox.min.css">
```

Comment: Try replacing date() by gmdate()

Comment: where is our webhost located in relation to you? Could it be that the server is in a different timezone?

Comment: that was it @Jarzon. Make it an answer and explain please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing date() by [gmdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)

gmdate returns a Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) that isn't relative to the timezone where you execute your code.